# How to use QSerialDevice in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port, qextserialport

I am trying to use QSerialDevice in Qt to get a connection to my serial port. I also tried QextSerialPort before (which works on Windows Vista but unfortunately not on Windows XP ..) but I need an API which supports XP, Vista and Win7...
I build the library and configured it this way:

```
CONFIG      += dll
CONFIG      += debug
```

I did use the current version from SVN (0.2.0 - 2010-04-05) and the 0.2.0 zip package.
After building the library I did copy it to my Qt Libdir (C:\Qt\2009.05\qt\lib) and also to C:\Windows\system32. Now I try to link against the lib in my project file:

```
LIBS += -lqserialdevice
```

I import the needed header (abstractserial.h) and use my own AbstractSerial like this:

```
// Initialize
this->serialPort->setDeviceName("COM1");
if (!this->serialPort->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Unbuffered))
  qWarning() << "Error" << this->serialPort->errorString();

// Configure SerialPort
this->serialPort->setBaudRate(AbstractSerial::BaudRate4800);
this->serialPort->setDataBits(AbstractSerial::DataBits8);
this->serialPort->setFlowControl(AbstractSerial::FlowControlOff);
this->serialPort->setParity(AbstractSerial::ParityNone);
this->serialPort->setStopBits(AbstractSerial::StopBits1);
```

The problem is, that if I run my application, it crashes immediately with exit code -1073741515 (application failed to initialize properly). This is the same error I got using QextSerialPort under Windows XP (it worked with Windows Vista).
If I build the QSerialDevice lib with release config and also my program, it crashes immediately but with exit code -1073741819

Can someone help me with this program or with another solution of getting a serial port to work with Qt (maybe another API or something?) Otherwise I have to use Windows API functions which would mean that my program won't work with UNIX systems..
If you have a solution for the problem with QextSerialPort under WinXP SP3, they are also welcome ;)

Best Regards,
Tobias

Comment: Windows error codes are easier in hex - they're bitfields. Also, those codes are much easier googlable. For instance, almosty all developers know by heart what `0xC0000005` is.

Comment: -1073741515 is 0xc0000135, STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND.  Just make sure the missing DLL is present in the EXE folder, whatever it might be.  Look in the Windows application event log.

Comment: Sorry but where can I find this logfile?

Comment: You can try using depends (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see what DLLs your application is trying to load and which ones it is not finding.

  [1]:

Comment: You should not use QSerialDevice as it is now unworked on, and also, it had several flaws which we fixed in QtSerialPort when the project was migrating to upstream Qt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tobias,

try use from SVN:
svn checkout svn://scm.fireforge.net/svnroot/qserialdevice